# where clause return empty row in view mysql

Tags: mysql, view, union

i have two tables with the schema below:

```
INCOME TABLE:
INCOME_ID, INCOME_NAME, INCOME_DATE

OUTCOME TABLE:
OUTCOME_ID, OUTCOME_NAME, OUTCOME_DATE

EXAMPLE DATA INCOME
INCOME_ID | INCOME_NAME | INCOME_DATE
1         | FIRST EXMPL | 24-07-2016
2         | SEC EXAMPLE | 25-07-2016
ETC
EXAMPLE DATA OUTCOME
OUTCOME_ID | OUTCOME_NAME | OUTCOME_DATE
1          | FIRST        | 24-07-2016
2          | SEC          | 03-08-2016
ETC
```

so i use union all to combine these table

```
SELECT INCOME_DATE AS DATE, INCOME_NAME AS NAME FROM INCOME
UNION ALL
SELECT OUTCOME_DATE, OUTCOME NAME FROM OUTCOME
```

and i use query above to create view

```
CREATE VIEW V_BALANCE AS SELECT INCOME_DATE AS DATE, INCOME_NAME AS NAME
UNION ALL
SELECT OUTCOME_DATE, OUTCOME_NAME FROM OUTCOME
```

the view was succesfully created but when i want to add where clause in view, it returns empty row

```
SELECT * FROM V_BALANCE WHERE DATE BETWEEN = '24-07-2016' AND '03-08-2016'
```

Comment: What's the datatype of `INCOME_DATE` and `OUTCOME_DATE`?

Comment: The _string_ '24-07-2016' is > '03-08-2016'.  Those are invalid dates.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the two date columns are indeed `DATE` columns, the problem is that you are not using proper format in the date literals. Use ANSI format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM V_BALANCE 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2016-07-24' 
               AND '2016-08-03' ;
```

See the documentation for other options: **[Date and time literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)**.

---

If the two date columns are not `DATE` but some `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, then the issue is there. Convert the columns to the proper date type, otherwise the comparisons will work incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code:

You wrote

- `SELECT * FROM V_BALANCE WHERE DATE BETWEEN = '24-07-2016' AND '03-08-2016'`

whereas you should have written

- `SELECT * FROM V_BALANCE WHERE DATE BETWEEN '24-07-2016' AND '03-08-2016'`

I know that that this sort of thing is very difficult to spot when you're reading back through code. I didn't see it either - I had to create the views and actually run your command before my client showed up the error.

Your client tool should have given you a warning about something this obvious.

Suggestion - maybe you should look at changing client tool? p.s. welcome to the forum.